# How to install py3exiv2 on the Mac OS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

Python 3.7.2, pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

**boost.python3** and **exiv2** installed

I tried install py3exiv2 on the Mac OS and got the error:

```
Processing ./py3exiv2-0.4.0.tar.gz
    Building wheels for collected packages: py3exiv2
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for py3exiv2 ... error
      Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/wf/jcp2vlzx003cjqtxh2vffq400000gn/T/pip-req-build-lvelibwj/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/wf/jcp2vlzx003cjqtxh2vffq400000gn/T/pip-wheel-t2tb7izo --python-tag cp37:
      find: /usr//local/kerio/vpnclient/config: Permission denied
      find: /usr//local/kerio/vpnclient/dbSSL: Permission denied
      find: /usr//sbin/authserver: Permission denied
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.7/pyexiv2
      copying src/pyexiv2/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.7/pyexiv2
      copying src/pyexiv2/exif.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.7/pyexiv2
      copying src/pyexiv2/iptc.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.7/pyexiv2
      copying src/pyexiv2/metadata.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.7/pyexiv2
      copying src/pyexiv2/preview.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.7/pyexiv2
      copying src/pyexiv2/utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.7/pyexiv2
      copying src/pyexiv2/xmp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.7/pyexiv2
      running build_ext
      building 'libexiv2python' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.7/src
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/exiv2wrapper.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.7/src/exiv2wrapper.o -g
      src/exiv2wrapper.cpp:54:18: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Exiv2::Error' (aka 'BasicError<char>')
          Exiv2::Error error(0);
                       ^     ~
      /usr/local/include/exiv2/error.hpp:263:11: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const Exiv2::BasicError<char>' for 1st argument
          class BasicError : public AnyError {
                ^
      /usr/local/include/exiv2/error.hpp:268:18: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'Exiv2::ErrorCode' for 1st argument
              explicit BasicError(ErrorCode code);
                       ^
      /usr/local/include/exiv2/error.hpp:272:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
              BasicError(ErrorCode code, const A& arg1);
          ^
```

.....

```
  /usr/local/include/exiv2/error.hpp:276:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 1 was provided
          BasicError(ErrorCode code, const A& arg1, const B& arg2);
          ^
  /usr/local/include/exiv2/error.hpp:280:9: note: candidate constructor template not viable: requires 4 arguments, but 1 was provided
          BasicError(ErrorCode code, const A& arg1, const B& arg2, const C& arg3);
          ^
  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  20 errors generated.
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for py3exiv2
```